# show Rstp stream in c#

Tags: c#, url, video-streaming, ip-camera, ozeki

I'm programming `c#`. I want to capture `video stream` and use each frame for processing. Video stream is captured from an `IP cammera` under `RSTP` protocol. I use Vmax Camera (model: vx-1311FHB which supports `ONVIF`) also I use `Ozeki` library to capture video from this url:

rtsp://192.168.1.66:554/Streaming/Channels/1?transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_1

but I can't see any response or image from cammera.

I test this url on VLC media player. Named software(VLC media player) show stream video but my code can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nvlc.nvlc is wrapper of libvlc for c#.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC